# EOF Error Pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I am looping through a list of Pickled files and some of my files have EOF Errors, which means they did not write properly. Is there a way to loop around the files that have these errors and continue to the next file instead of the entire script stopping?

Answer (score 1):

Use `try/except`:

```
for pkl_file in pkls:
     try:
         obj = pickle.load(..) # or however you load the file
     except EOFError:
         continue
     # rest of code, handling obj
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ensure that you are opening the pickle files in *binary* mode as this is a potential cause of EOF errors when reading/writing pickle data.

When you are reading the pickle files use `rb` mode when calling [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open). Similarly, if it is your code that is writing the pickle files, ensure that the files are written in binary mode by specifying mode `wb`.

Secondly catch the exception and ignore it, where "ignore" means that you issue a warning message so any genuinely bad pickle files will be noticed.

```
import cPickle as pickle

for filename in pickle_files:
    try:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            data = pickle.load(f)
            # use the data
    except EOFError as exc:
        print(exc)
```